# Update TextEntry of WebBrowser in Python

Tags: python, quickly

I got a basic web browser set up and working with Quickly and Python code, but how do I set it up so my TextEntry object (where the URL is entered) to update if I click on a link on the webpage. It's sorta strange for it to display http://www.google.com when I click YouTube on the google homepage to go to youtube and the entry not update.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using WebKit. You'll have to connect to the `load-status` property signal to see if a new page is being requested and change the netry accordingly.

Here's a bit of code from an old project of mine.

```
    # Snipped init and stuff...
    self._webview = WebKit.WebView()
    self._webview.connect('notify::load-status', self.on_load_status)

def on_load_status(self, webview, status):
    status = webview.get_load_status()
    if status == WebKit.LoadStatus.COMMITTED:
        self._set_loading(True)
        self._entry.set_text(webview.get_uri())
    elif status == WebKit.LoadStatus.FINISHED:
        self._set_loading(False)

def _set_loading(self, loading):
    self._stop.set_sensitive(loading)
    self._reload.set_sensitive(not loading)
    self._back.set_sensitive(self._webview.can_go_back())
    self._forward.set_sensitive(self._webview.can_go_forward())
```

The `_set_loading()` method is used to enable/disable the stop/reload/back/forward buttons on the toolbar. If you don't have those, leave it out (otherwise, change the names to your needs ofcourse).